# After mouseup EventListener prevent click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function initDrag(event)
    {
        var lastOffset  = context.getElementTranslation(element);

        // Get initial coordinates for (x,y)
        initialX        = event.pageX;
        initialY        = event.pageY;

        // Determine last offset points for (x,y)
        lastOffsetX     = lastOffset ? lastOffset[0] : 0;
        lastOffsetY     = lastOffset ? lastOffset[1] : 0;
        startOffsetX    = initialX - lastOffsetX;
        startOffsetY    = initialY - lastOffsetY;

        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();

        elem.className = elem.className + ' draggable';

        document.documentElement.addEventListener('mousemove', doDrag, false);
        document.documentElement.addEventListener('mouseup', stopDrag, false);
    }

 jQuery('.classname').on('click', function(event)
 {

  alert(23);
  jQuery('.medium-editor-button-first').attr('style','');

        if(!event.shiftKey)
        {
            if(layer.hasClass('layer_selected'))
            {
                event.stopPropagation();
                return false;
            }
            context.deselectAllLayers();
            context.setLayerSelected(layerId);
        }
        else
        {
            /*if(jQuery('.layer_selected').length < 1 )
            {
                context.deselectAllLayers();
            }*/
            if(layer.hasClass('layer_selected'))
            {
                layer.removeClass('layer_selected multiSelectLayers');
                context.initializeMultiSelect(layer);
                event.stopPropagation();
                return false;
            }

            context.selectors.multiSelect.removeClass('layer_selected');
        }

        layer.find('.tp-caption').focus();

        layer.addClass("layer_selected");
        context.initializeMultiSelect(layerId);

        event.stopPropagation();
    });
```

After each mouse up click function fire. I want to prevent this click event. I tried  **event.stopPropagation();** and **event.preventDefault();** but didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider setting up a demo @ https://jsfiddle.net/, so we can debug your code.

Comment: Define 'does not work'. What happens? How can you know the click event did in fact fire?

Comment: @StijndeWitt  i have place alert(23); in click event function. so on every mouseup event it call

Comment: @Nilang `stopPropagation` does not stop *your* events from firing, it stops *other* event listeners higher up the tree from receiving them. I think you should explain what you are trying to do, because your current use case as described is attaching an event listener to stop an event from firing... ?